# Import Unity Scene in UnityPlayer(Android/iOS) Cardboard and DayDream

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, android-unity-plugin

I have multiple scene in my project and I don't want to embed all scene in apk because of size of application. I want to import the .unityproject or unity scene dynamically(download from internet) and render it in app. Is it possible ? 
Do we have any other possible way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.Download the scene from the internet with the `WWW` API. 2.Load the downloaded scene. Which part are you having hard time with? You should update your question with your code and where you are stuck....

Answer (score 0):

I think Unity only compiles (to apk in this case) the scenes added to the File-Build menu. So you just need to remove the scenes you don't want to compile in that menu.

The exception is the Resources folder. Any folder named "Resources" is "copied" into the APK.

You also can take a look of other ways to reduce the file size: https://www.google.pl/search?q=reduce+apk+unity&oq=reduce+apk+unity